# What should I put for my SPF record?

Tags: spf

I find the SPF Record Syntax at http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax extremely cryptic and I don't understand it.

I have a number of PCs running jobs and which have to send out status emails. The domain of the sender email accounts for these notification emails is, say, `a.b.c.net`.  These PCs have private IP addresses on a LAN whose Internet connection is on DHCP, and hence their public IP address changes regularly.

These PCs are forward their mail to smtp.1and1.com to relay. Login credentials are required before smtp.1and1.com will relay.

What should the SPF record for a.b.c.net contain?

If I ping smtp.1and1.com, it is now 74.208.5.2, but I find that its value changes periodically. I inspected emails sent in this manner and the first relay is always:

```
Received: from WINSHUS62 ([172.23.131.14]) by mrelay.perfora.net (mreueus002)
with ESMTPA (Nemesis) id 0M6URR-1Zth2s3kHT-00yRU8; Fri, 11 Mar 2016 15:55:41
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are relaying all your mails through 1&1's mail-servers, it will be their mail servers that will be checked for SPF on the receiving end.

I have not been able to find any official information from 1&1 about what SPF record to use, but the SPF record for 1und1.com contains the 74.208.5.2 server, so with a little luck that record will contain all outgoing servers from 1&1.

So you SPF (TXT) record for a.b.c.net could look like this:

```
v=spf1 include:1und1.com ~all
```

This should pass all mails sent through 1&1's servers, and Softfail all others. You can change the ~all to -all if you want to Fail all other addresses.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to have more than one authorized mail forwarders?  For programmatic sends, I use 1&1, but for email, actually it is hosted by Google Apps.  So I am afraid that above SPF record would kill all other human sent mails.

Comment: Yes, you can just add  include:_spf.google.com to the record. But have you considered using Google Apps for you programmatic sends also: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en, then you would only need the _spf.google.com include. This would reduce the number of required DNS queries and reduce the risk of running into the DNS Lookup Limit of many SPF implementations.

Comment: Your original answer works for me after I added as a TXT record and not a SPF record. Now my notification messages are not tagged with a red `?` when received in Gmail.  Regarding adding _spf.google.com, what's the exact syntax?  It is `v=spf1 include:1und1.com ~all include _spf.google.com`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your full TXT (SPF) record should look like this: `v=spf1 include:1und1.com include:_spf.google.com ~all`. You need to have the `all` mechanism at the end, else the second include will never be evaluated.

Answer (score 7):

Found your post because I was having the same issue, so including the below in case others encounter the same issue and are looking for an answer.

I have a server which is sending authenticated email through 1and1's servers at smtp.1and1.es, but it looks like any of their domains (1and1.com, 1and1.de etc) all use the same servers too. Sadly 1and1 don't appear to include the answer in their FAQ/help pages, however they do publish this page [Email servers](http://postmaster.1and1.com/en/email-server/) which lists their email servers used for outbound customer emails. After some digging, the answer appears to be to use this SPF record:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de ~all
```

Whether to use `~all` (SoftFail) or `-all` (Fail) is probably a separate debate.

The key thing is to include `include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de` in the SPF TXT record for your domain.

Comment: Updated link on [ionos](https://www.ionos.com/help/domains/configuring-mail-servers-and-other-related-records/using-an-spf-record-to-prevent-spam/). It is now sufficient to add a SPF [DNS record](https://my.ionos.fr/add-dns-record/) (chose option `softfail` or `hardfail`), with no other input, and it adds `v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de ~all` (`~` stands for softfail)

Answer (score 2):

1and1 now gives the option to auto generate a SPF record for their mail server. Go to the "1&1 mail server SPF records" section of your domain admin.

Answer (score 0):

Current advice from within the ionos panel as of 30/04/2021 :

In the Value field, enter the statement for authorising the IONOS mail servers. You can choose between the Softfail and Hardfail settings.

If you want to use the Softfail setting, add the following:
v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de ~all

If you want to use the Hardfail setting instead, enter the following:
v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de -all